# Windows 10 search not finding previously installed programs

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-search

I recently added a SSD to my laptop. So I installed Windows 10 on it, cleaned the system partition on my HDD and kept the "Data" one. But on this "Data" partition there are some programs installed; and when I open the start menu and searches for these programs, they don't appear. This seems relatively reasonable to me, as Windows can't know they are installed. How do I make them appear? Does adding this partition to the indexed locations work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Does adding this partition to the indexed locations work?" - That will indeed help but these programs should be installed again because of the fact the registry knows nothing about them at this point.

Comment: Oh, so I should reinstall all of them? This kinda sucks :/

Comment: You have to re-install them. Anyway a lot of them will not work without re-installing them because of missing system files, registry entries,....

Comment: Alright then. Thanks you guys for your answers, it'll teach me to try to play clever